# Linear/Integer Programming - Count consecutive ones.

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I am trying to model the following scenario:

If $L_0=0, L_1=0, L_2=0, L_3=1, L_4=1, L_5=0, L_6=0, L_7=1, L_8=1, L_9=1, L_{10}=0$

I would like to create a new variable that keeps track of consecutive times L is 1 before turning back to zero.

That is, I would like to create a new variable with the following output:
$Z_1=0, Z_2=0, Z_3=0, Z_4=0, Z_5=2, Z_6=0, Z_7=0, Z_8=0, Z_9=0, Z_{10}=3$.

I need help with modelling this in an LP.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly doing what you want is difficult. Usually we can get away with simpler things because we know more about the model. But let's try anyway: call the original binary variables $x_i \in \{0,1\}$.

First introduce an integer variable $a_i$ (accumulator) that is defined by:
$$a_i = \begin{cases} a_{i-1}+1 & \text{if $x_i=1$ }\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

This can be modeled as:
$$\begin{align}
   & a_{i-1}+1 - (1-x_i)M \le a_i \le a_{i-1}+1 + (1-x_i)M\\
   & 0 \le a_i \le x_i M \end{align}$$

Now we need:
$$z_i = \begin{cases} a_{i-1} & \text{if $x_i=0$ and $x_{i-1}=1$ }\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

This can be modeled as:
$$\begin{align}
   & a_{i-1} - x_i M - (1-x_{i-1})M \le z_i \le a_{i-1} + x_i M + (1-x_{i-1})M\\
   & 0 \le z_i \le x_{i-1} M \\& z_i\le (1-x_i)M \end{align}$$

The results look like:

```
----     71 VARIABLE x.L  

i3 1.000,    i4 1.000,    i7 1.000,    i8 1.000,    i9 1.000


----     71 VARIABLE a.L  

i3 1.000,    i4 2.000,    i7 1.000,    i8 2.000,    i9 3.000


----     71 VARIABLE z.L  

i5  2.000,    i10 3.000
```

(Only nonzero values are printed).

Notes:

- I doubt this is actually what you need in your model as there is usually a way to exploit knowledge from the rest of the model.
- This is impossible to model as an LP: you need a MIP.
- A good value for $M$ is the largest possible number of consecutive ones. E.g. $M= \mathit{card}(i)$.

Comment: Very nice, as always!

Comment: @Reddy Out of curiosity, can you tell us a bit about the problem and why you need this particular construct?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen The problem that I am trying to formulate is similar to an assignment problem. Specifically, the decision variable of the model is to assign a job to different machines every day. If a machine is idle on a particular day, I have L=0 or if a machine is assigned a job on a particular day, I have L=1. If the machine is idle, I assign a penalty. This penalty increases with the number of consecutive days that the machine is idle. I.e., there is a different penalty if the machine is idle for 2 consecutive days compared to if the machine is idle for 3 consecutive days.

Comment: That looks to me like a very different question. I don't see why the $z_i$'s are needed for this.

Comment: The penalty is a function of z_i

Answer (score 1):

At the price of more variables ($n²$), you can get a much stronger formulation avoiding big-M indicator constraints. Let $y_{ij} = (1-L_{i-1}) L_i \dots L_j (1-L_{j+1})$, this can be linearized as
$$ y_{ij} \leq 1-L_{i-1} $$
$$ y_{ij} \leq L_k \quad i \leq k \leq j $$
$$ y_{ij} \leq 1-L_{j+1} $$
$$ y_{ij} \ge \sum_{k=i,\dots,j} L_k - L_{i-1} - L_{j+1} - (j-i)$$
and finally
$$ z_j = \sum_{i=1,\dots,j} (j-i+1) y_{ij}$$
(assuming border cases $L_0=0$ and $L_{n+1} = 0$).

I think this gives the convex hull (assuming $L_i$ are binaries).

Comment: Very good indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Besides about $n^2/2$ variables, this also generates about $n^3/6$ equations. Not immediately clear if this will be more efficient in practice.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Indeed, but a good candidate for a Benders decomposition :) (or simply using lazy constraints might help).